# Counting a specific word in a console

Tags: java

i'm pretty new to Java and i'm wondering how to count a specific word from a console
Example, I want to have a +1 to the counting whenever a line contains "Runes"

[image]

Comment: Count how often it is sent to the console.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increment a variable every time Runes is printed you can do it like that:
Instead of `System.out.println("Tormented Demon #8: 550x Death Runes");` you write a own method like this

```
public void printToConsole(String str) {
    if(str.contains("Runes")) {
        this.runesPrintedCounting++;
    }
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

If you want to print `"Tormented Demon #8: 551x Death Runes"` instead of `"Tormented Demon #8: 550x Death Runes"` it's a bit more complicated: You could work that out with a **regex**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but, if the string was already in the console and i wanted to count the lines that area already in the console that contain a word is that possible?

Comment: I don't know, didn't that before and so I cannot say if it's possible. Anyway I don't think that its a good idea, you should count before you output it.